# How to disallow particular subfolder in robot.txt?

Tags: html, url, web-crawler, robots.txt, google-crawlers

Here is my code

Example URL pattern

```
www.example.com/folder/subfolder/*
```

Want to Allow  `www.example.com/folder/*` and Disallow particularly

```
www.example.com/folder/subfolder/*
```

How to implement in robot.txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disallow a folder specifically by adding this line to robots.txt

```
Disallow: /folder/subfolder/
```

Comment: Is this wont cause any issue for other Main folder paths right?

Comment: No, it won't cause any issues for other main folder paths